# how can I speed up the process of summing values in this python code?

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, append

I have df.Ah, column of a dataframe, which has  either positive values or zeros. I want to store into one another dataframe the sum  of values before a zero  and follow that with one another zero.

for example : df.Ah = [ 1,2,3,0,46,0,24,1] , gives as  out put [6,0,46,0,25].

my attempt was:

```py
lst = df.Ah;
lst1 = pd.DataFrame(index=np.arange(100000000)); #if I replace values of a pre-existing column code #speeds up


summ = 0;
for i , elem in enumerate(lst):
     
    if elem != 0:
        summ = summ + elem;
    else:
        if summ:
            lst1.loc[i,'Ah']=sum;
            
        lst1.loc[i,'Ah']=elem;
        summ = 0;
...

if summ:
    lst1.iloc[i+1, 0] = summ;

#If I print the index i for each loop , it generates 100.000 prints for each minute;
# which means it would take around five hours to complete checking 31 milion values
# of my dataframe and I don't have all that time for this basic operation.
```

is there a way to speed up this code ?